# Is there any Node.js issue trackers out there?

Tags: javascript, node.js, project-management, collaboration, issue-tracking

All I can find now is [omega](https://github.com/wachunga/omega), which uses WebSockets and updates in real-time. Which is good, but still in development stage.

I would like to know if there is any handy, ready for production use issue trackers that has hooks, or somehow integrates with Git or SVN.

Answer (score 7):

[Trello](https://trello.com/) is built in Node and uses socket.io and websockets. You can read about their stack [here](http://blog.fogcreek.com/the-trello-tech-stack/). My team used it before we switched to Assembla right when I started. But Trello was great, and I believe that it integrates with Git.

Comment: Trello is awesome, but I had no idea it was written in Node.

Comment: I tried Trello months ago, didn't know it integrates with Git. How do I set that up?

Comment: You can check out the [github-trello gem](https://github.com/zanker/github-trello). It allows you to reference an issue with a commit, etc.

Comment: Did that solve your issue, @Vicary?

Comment: Not exactly what I want, our team doesn't bother spend the time to setup a local Trello server at the moment (was expecting to use trello.com directly).

Comment: The information is useful though, up voted.

Comment: I wonder if one of us misread that gem? The documentation doesn't look to me like you set up a local Trello server, but that the gem adds a path where your commits will send data to your Trello board (on trello.com) through the API with the use of your API key.

Comment: We have a local git repo instead of Github, looks like it takes a lot more work for local hook scripts.

Answer (score -1):

What about rollbar.com? (works client side and server side, integrates with github)

Comment: I am not looking for paid, or even hosted platforms.